# Top most class of ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.1

Tags: ruby

This is my interview questions.

Which one is the top most class of ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.1?

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily check that yourself by getting the `superclass` chain of any class

Comment: @NiklasB. true.class => TrueClass and TrueClass.superclass => Object and Object.superclass => nil So, can you please explain this?.

Comment: May i know, why did you put the down vote?

Comment: @Mr.Black: What's the conclusion you'd personally draw from that? By the way, the downvotes are probably because the lacks *any* kind of research effort.

Comment: Nobody knows everything in the world. Everyone makes mistake sometimes maybe he is genius too.

Comment: Though it is true that nobody knows everything in the world, the top class of Ruby is very easy to find. http://ruby-doc.org

Comment: Same question  in Interview ... +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `Object` for 1.8 and `BasicObject` for 1.9. Using `ancestors` would have been an easy way to find this out by yourself:

```
1.class.ancestors.last
#=> BasicObject
```

Comment: @michaelKohi Many Thanks. I don't care about the down votes. Because, nobody answering me. They are laughing about my question. Nobody knows everything in the world.

Comment: Don't worry, we were all beginners at one point. :-) But for the future you should really try to find answers like this on your own, IRB/Pry are great for exploring Ruby. BTW: you should accept this answer unless you need any more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm clear from you answer and comment too.

Comment: What about RUby 2.0 ? Same happens here Interview question

Comment: Same. Why didn't you just try out the command?